# Error calling method on NPObject! in uploadify

Tags: javascript, flash, uploadify

I am having Uploadify plugin for uploading files. It was working fine and suddenly it stopped working. I am not able to fix. It would be great if I get some help here

**Mycode :**

```
jQuery(".fileSelectBox  > input:checked").each(function(){

    if( !jQuery(this).parent().parent('div').hasClass('completed')){                        
             jQuery('#file').uploadifyUpload(jQuery(this).parent().parent('div').attr('id').replace('file',''));                        
    }
 });
```

**Getting Error in the following line**

```
document.getElementById(jQuery(this).attr('id') + 'Uploader').startFileUpload(ID, checkComplete);
```

Comment: @Cameron    the error is Error calling method on NPObject! on the console

Comment: (I should read titles more carefully!) Hmm. Very odd. I'm afraid I'm not much help, though I did see this as well recently while working on my own file-uploading widget. I think it comes from inside jQuery somewhere... Good luck!